# c++ Factory. Child constructor not accessible from parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, factory

I'm making a socket factory. I want every external application to use the interface of the Socket class that is the parent of a few classes (ServerSocketTCP, ClientSocketTCP, ServerSocketUDP and so on) because eventually socket will be use to read and write independently of the type, simplifying the use of them. So sockets will be only constructed by a socket static member (The factory). That why children constructors are protected in order to avoid users to create them.

Here is where I got the error:

```
class A{
protected:
   A();
public:
   static A* createClass(int _type){
      switch(_type){
       case 0:
         return new B();
       case 1:
         return new C();
       default:
         return nullptr;
      }
   }
}

class B: public A{
protected:
    B();
}

class C: public A{
protected:
    C();
}
```

Then the compiler says that the constructors of B and C are not accessible from A. Is there any way to do what I want? I thought that it was possible to access children protected member but now I see that not because the access inheritance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems with your code. Except for missing `;` after the class definition you are also implementing the factory in a wrong way.

In general you have a Producer that produces products. The products all share a base class that normal users should not be able to instantiate (e.g. pure virtual or protected ctor). According to what the client chooses, the Producer creates an instance of the product and delivers it back. So if your product ctors are `private` you need to declare the producer as a `friend` in order to be able to access the respective ctors.

Now the producer delivers some pointer to a base product which can be downcasted to the type you need. So an compiling example (picked yours and modified it accordingly) would read like this:

```
class Producer;
class BaseProduct {
    protected:
    BaseProduct() {}
};

class Product_B : public BaseProduct { 
    friend class Producer;
    private:
        Product_B();
};

class Product_C : public BaseProduct {
    friend class Producer;
    private:
        Product_C();
};

class Producer{
    private:
        Producer();
    public:
        static BaseProduct* createProduct_Class(int _type){
            switch(_type){
                case 0:
                    return new Product_B;
                case 1:
                    return new Product_C;
                default:
                    return nullptr;
            }
        }
};
```

Please be aware that using the factory pattern wrongly can result quickly in anti-patterns.

EDIT: Plus you should not forget to extend your producer class to manage deletion etc. There are many books and websites that handle all kinds of patterns. One good book is "Object-oriented Software Engineering from Bernd Brügge", but of course there are a lot more of them.

Comment: Watch out not to off-topic the question to the factory pattern design: you can describe and suggest a better way but the primary problem was the accessibility problem

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've given, the factory method can't even see the B and C class definitions, so it can't possibly use them, no matter whether a parent can access a child's protected members or not (it can't, as noted by Marco A.).

You need to move the implementation of the factory method to a cpp file where it can see all of the class defintions. Then you'll get errors about the constructors being protected, and you can deal with those appropriately (presumably by making friends).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, th compiler is complaining because B and C constructors and `protected, and no friendship exists. So A cannot call those constructors.

The correct design is to separate the Factory type from the class hierarchy, not to put it in the base class.